# Class 'Mage_Affiliate_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: php

I am trying to make a module with some settings I can change via system configuration

they explained me here:
[How to make some parameters editable via admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/how-to-make-some-parameters-editable-via-admin)

However I am having the following problem

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Affiliate_Helper_Data' not found in /home/theprint/public_html/preprod/app/Mage.php on line 547

The structure is as follows:

Should I create a data.php empty?

http://screencast.com/t/mOnMlNKun

Update 1:

this is my config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Model</class>
            </luisvalencia_affiliate>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
            </luisvalencia_affiliate>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                        <class>luisvalencia_affiliate/observer</class>
                        <method>captureReferral</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </luisvalencia_affiliate>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see that your error is Class `'Mage_Affiliate_Helper_Data' not found  that means  helper name should be affiliate` that means **Mage::helper('affiliate');**
 and need to add this code in config.xml file

```
    ....
        <global>
....
<!-- add this code in global tag in  global -->
            <helpers>
                 <affiliate>
                       <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
                 </affiliate>
            </helpers>
.....
        </global>
```

**And  Need to define helper class and helper file is Data.php**(`Luisvalencia/Affiliate/Helper/Data.php`)

```
<?php 
class Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

**Edit:According to your code**

```
<helpers>
            <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
            </luisvalencia_affiliate>
        </helpers>
```

should be

```
 <helpers>
                 <affiliate>
                       <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
                 </affiliate>
            </helpers>
```

Comment: who and why is given negative marks... i cannot understand .. there are two times, i got negative marks  in other questions... can any one tell me what happen

Comment: I already did, and I still get Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Affiliate_Helper_Data' not found in /home/theprint/public_html/preprod/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: pls check screenshot, http://screencast.com/t/fnLn2zi52

Comment: it works, but then why my observer works without any problem! seems strange http://screencast.com/t/yjnXBb7SJW58

Comment: is getStoreConfig get proper value???

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to define your helper class. This includes two steps

**Define helper class inside `config.xml`**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
             <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                   <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
             </luisvalencia_affiliate>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Declare your Helper Class**

location: `app/code/community/Luisvalencia/Affiliate/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php 
class Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

Now you can refer you helper like this.

```
 Mage::helper('luisvalencia_affiliate');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I updated my question, whats my missing piece on config?

Comment: sorry, my answer was not aligned properly. Now you can see my code

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a Data.php file like

```
<?php class Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

and declare it in your module config too. This normally happens when you try to call `__()` to translate something.