# How to add a layout handle before configurable product is loaded?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, event-observer, configurable-product, layout-update

## Synopsis

I need to add a layout handle for a configurable product view, this will allow me to insert necessary javascript into the page for JS based validation.  The server-side validation is outside of the scope of this question.

I have created a simple module that observers `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view` I have implemented logging to see the observers is triggered, and sets a new handle which does nothing.

Although my JS files doesn't exist I would expect to see a 404 error.

## Example

*config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Example>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <vendor_example>
                <class>Vendor_Example_Model</class>
            </vendor_example>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <vendor_example>
                        <class>Vendor_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setLayout</method>
                    </vendor_example>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <vendor_example>
                    <file>Vendor_Example.xml</file>
                </vendor_example>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*Model/Observer.php*

```
<?php

class Vendor_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function setLayout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        if ($action instanceof Mage_Catalog_ProductController
            && $action->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'view'
        ) {

            $id          = $action->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $product     = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($id);
            $productType = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

            if ($productType instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable) {

                $handle = 'vendor_example_configurable_plate';
                $action->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handle);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

*design/frontend/package/theme/layout/vendor_example.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <vendor_example_configurable>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>example/test.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </vendor_example_configurable>

    <vendor_example_configurable_plate>
        <update handle="vendor_example_configurable" />

        <reference name="before_footer_ends">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/test/ivalid.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </vendor_example_configurable_plate>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to add a js file for configurable product, you really dont want to do this. Create a `local.xml` inside your theme layout location and put this code inside

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/test.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

and put your js file in skin location

File : `skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/js/test.js`

`PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` is the unique handler that is render by magento, for configurable products only. So you are lucky.. For each product type, there are unique handlers. Magento use this handler in order to put product type specific layout. Take a look on `catalog.xml`.

### EDIT

In that case, you can go for an alternate solution. You can add a template file through this handler and do your insertion of js file there. This would be more reliable method than go for an event observation.

So these are the steps

*1. Declare a template for configuration product*

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="configurable.js.block" template="configurable/js.phtml" />
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

*2. define a helper for your module and use it to provide js files, according to the need*

```
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

     public function getJsForProduct() {

          $product = Mage::registry('current_prouduct');
          $attribute = $product->getData('attribute_code');
          if($attribute == "something"){
               //returns js file here; file location is enough
          }
     } 
}
```

You need to define your helper class in config. For more [RefeR this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/class-mage-affiliate-helper-data-not-found/32329#32329)

*3.Define template file*

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/configurable/js.phtml`<

```
<div>
    <?php $js = Mage::helper('your_helper_alias')->getJsForProduct(); ?>
     <script src="<?php echo $js ?>" ></script>
</div>
```

You can simply get attribute in template file itself. However I showed you a reliable method that you can go with. I didn't test this. But you can make it work.

Comment: Thanks dude, although this doesn't quite solve my problem because there are many types configurable products - sheets, pipes, bars etc. that have their own JS file with different custom options and price calculators;  So i needed to get the product and determine it's type based on `the attribute_set_id`.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please go through it

Comment: After looking over that i'll give it a go, it looks like it would do the job; cheers.